# Why is there no article for "president" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles

In the following sentence:

> I decided not to vote for your candidate for president.

I thought that the article "the" is needed for the word "president", because there is usually only one president. But I found that using the article is not correct, or at least not preferred.

Why does this sentence lack the article?

Comment: President, mayor, Member of Parliament, chairman, etc, are the names of positions or posts which do not require articles. He became chairman, she was elected mayor, etc.

Comment: What is the source? Could you add a link to it IN your question, please?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is from Duolingo Russian course (learn Russian on English) - https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/11895305/I-decided-not-to-vote-for-your-candidate-for-president

Comment: It's an odd sentence, it could be worded better, e.g. "I didn't vote for Johnson to be **the leader** of the party / **prime minister** of the UK.”  AND... “I didn't vote Johnson **for Prime Minister**”, “Johnson **became Prime Minister** in 2019” all forms are acceptable.

Comment: I think that the definite article is used when we *identify* which PM, President, monarch we are referring to and nearly always at the beginning of a sentence. The Indian Prime Minister, the Queen of Denmark, the President of the USA, the Chairman/person of XY etc.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as it stands is thus.

- I decided not to vote for your candidate for president.

A candidate stands for office. There is an implied "the office of" here.

- I decided not to vote for your candidate for *the office of* president.

It is very usual to leave out that part. Usually people will only put that in when they are trying to be formal, or when they are using it to to make a speech and they want to have a particular rhetorical effect. It becomes a verbal fanfare that gives an annoucement an air of seriousness. And sometimes a newspaper will put it in a headline for siimilar motivations.

- I give you our candidate for *the office of* president.

You can either put in the "the office of" part or you can leave it out. You can't put in only part of it. So the following would be wrong.

- I decided not to vote for your candidate for *the* president.

Answer (score 0):

"The president" refers to the person holding the office.  "President" refers to the office (position) itself.

Comment: I think some more clarification is needed in your answer. For example, with a title, "president" (without an article) can refer to the person, not the office: "President Biden signed the legislation."